# How do I 'share' a Meteor app for others to develop without having to re-create it every time?

Tags: meteor

What's the proper way to handle having multiple developers on a Meteor application? On each computer that I want to develop the app on I have to follow these steps to get it running after cloning from the repo:

1. Rename `my-app/` to `app/`
2. Run `meteor create my-app`
3. Move all files from `app/` into `my-app/`
4. Delete the auto generated `my-app.*`files
5. Re-add all packages (jquery, iron:router, etc...)

Note that I'm not including the `.meteor/local` directory in the repository.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but it's not making itself apparent.

Comment: Github has a decent default .gitignore you can use.  It only ignores the `.meteor/local` and `.meteor/meteorite` folders.  Everything else is, but it's definition, safe to include in your repo.  The .gitignore can be found here:  https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Meteor.gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Push to the repo all files at the same level as the `.meteor` directory. Nothing to rename or `meteor create`. Yes, packages do need to be added, but the list of packages is specified in a file inside `.meteor`.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the full .meteor/ directory in your repository. That way whenever the repo is cloned they will get the right version of meteor, a list of all the installed packages (which are downloaded at runtime) and any settings they need to run the app.

As far as I'm aware there is nothing in the .meteor/ directory that can't be shared across to different developers.